# Does the perimeter of a polygon necessarily decrease if more edges are added to it, with the constraint of constant area?

Tags: geometry, area

A circle has the lowest perimeter for a 2D shape of a given area. To my understanding, it can also be approximated by a polygon of infinite sides. So, if I take an n-sided polygon and gradually add edges to it, keeping my area constant, will the perimeter also gradually decrease(Since I am approaching a circle)?

Thanks!

Comment: This is certainly true if your $n$-gon is regular. But I'm not at all certain if you allow any $n$-sided polygon, in particular if it's not convex.

Comment: What if I add the constraint that the polygon has to be convex?

Comment: Interesting question. I suspect taht convexity, without necessarly regularity, could suffice...

Comment: I have to make an essential precisation to the previous comment: I meant that you keep increasing the number of sides of the convex polygon by adding new vertices WITHOUT removing the old ones (and then scaling down to conserve the area). Otherwise the statement can be easily contradicted (think again to the flattening of the shape of the polygon)

Comment: Some implicit assertions in the question are not true. Particularly, _every_ polygon is "approximated by a polygon of infinitely many sides" (think, e.g., of a triangle approximated by "increasingly flat" arcs of circles approximated by $n$-gons with large $n$).

Comment: @guestDiego An interesting alternative question: What assumptions are required to ensure that polygons with more edges have smaller perimeter (assuming fixed area)?

Comment: The remark of Millikan is right. So the question can be answered negatively

Comment: Since you don't explicitly mention convex in your question (even though it is in the comments below), consider the Koch Snowflake: a shape with infinite perimeter enclosing a finite area.  I think this is a counter example to your question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake

Answer (score 16):

Convexity is not sufficient.  Take a unit square with area $1$ and perimeter $4$.  Replace one side with an isosceles triangle with legs of length $100$.  The area is now about $51$ and the perimeter is $203$.  Scaling down linearly by $\sqrt {51}$ to make unit area leaves the perimeter $\frac {203}{\sqrt {51}}\approx 28.42$

Comment: Essentially, this example shows why "number of sides" is a terrible way to control a polygon: one can have any number of microscopic sides that inflate the side count but contribute virtually nothing to perimeter nor to area.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good example. To stretch this further, does my assumption hold if I include the constraints of both convexity and regularity?

Comment: Yes, and regular implies convex.  In that case guestDiego's answer applies.  The polygon then inscribes in a circle and you can draw radii from the center to each vertex and the center of each side, making twice as many right triangles as there are vertices.  You can then evaluate the perimeter and area.  This is how Archimedes approximated $\pi$

Comment: Maybe better to take triangle with legs of length 6? Then perimeter will be precisely 7.5.

Answer (score 11):

Depends on the details of how you add edges.  You could get polygons looking like this.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me how one deduces a counterexample from this...

Comment: @Semiclassical:  compare it to a regular polygon of half the sides and the same area.  It will look very much like a circle that is halfway between the inner points and the outer points.  It will have much smaller perimeter.

Comment: Hmm, thats interesting. It seems like my question was far too open-ended. Does your answer change if I add the constraint that the polygon should be convex?

Comment: @Arun:  No, it takes more than convexity.  See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I guess that you are supposing that you are dealing with convex regular polygons. If you don't make explicit this hypothesis, the claim is false. In fact, by adding sides and keeping constant area you can obtain polygons with perimeters tending to infinity. You simply need to make the shape flatter and flatter. On the other side, if you consider a sequence of convex regular polygons with the same area and an increasing number of sides, the claim is true. Of course it need to be proved carefully. You need to prove that for any convex $n$-regular polygon inscribed in a unit circle, whose perimeter is $P_n$ and area $A_n$, the ratio $A_n/P_n^2$ is increasing with $n$.